# How to make this foreach-object run correctly?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I'm trying to read a .csv with columns `CompanyName,UserCount` and edit an .rdp file. The output should create multiple .rdp file, while changing 3 lines in the .rdp itself and the name.

So far I have this:

```
$testRDP = (Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\Test.rdp)
$remoteAPP = @()
$rdpName = @()
$companyNames=Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\CompanyNames.csv
foreach ($name in $companyNames) {
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $name.UserCount; $i++) {
        $remoteAPP = "RemoteApp" + $name.CompanyName + ".address.com"
        $rdpName = $name.CompanyName + $i + ".rdp"
        $aliasRDP = $name.CompanyName + $i
        ForEach-Object {$testRDP -replace 'remoteapp.address.com', $remoteAPP}
        ForEach-Object {$testRDP -replace 'user', $aliasRDP} | 
Out-File C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\$rdpName
        }
}
```

Running this replaces the `'user'` with `$aliasRDP` but `'remoteapp.address.com'` stays the same.
I'm guessing that my pipeline is wrong. If I can clarify something better, let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: The first ForEachObject isn't piped anywhere.  Where does the output go?

Comment: @WalterMitty Moreover, they both doesn't have anything piped in them :)

Comment: I think the second foreach-object is piped to the out-file.

Answer (score 3):

In fact you don't need `ForEach-Object` at all:

```powershell
$testRDP = (Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\Test.rdp)
$remoteAPP = @()
$rdpName = @()
$companyNames=Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\CompanyNames.csv
foreach ($name in $companyNames) {
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $name.UserCount; $i++) {
        $remoteAPP = "RemoteApp" + $name.CompanyName + ".address.com"
        $rdpName = $name.CompanyName + $i + ".rdp"
        $aliasRDP = $name.CompanyName + $i
        $testRDP -replace 'remoteapp.address.com', $remoteAPP -replace 'user', $aliasRDP | 
Out-File C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\$rdpName
        }
}
```

Here is version that uses regex to match and replace strings. It's more safe, because original script will replace matches anywhere in file and that can be fatal.

```powershell
$testRDP = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\Test.rdp')
$companyNames = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\CompanyNames.csv'
foreach ($name in $companyNames) {
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $name.UserCount; $i++) {
            $remoteAPP = 'RemoteApp' + $name.CompanyName + '.address.com'
            $rdpName = $name.CompanyName + $i + '.rdp'
            $aliasRDP = $name.CompanyName + $i
            $testRDP -replace '^(full address:s:).*$', "`$1$remoteAPP" -replace '^(username:s:).*$', "`$1$aliasRDP" |
                Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Administrator.PT\Desktop\$rdpName"
    }
}
```